# How many router outlets can i use in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, frontend

Hello i just want to know how many router-outlets i can use in angular, is there any limit?

if so how many?

---

Here is the link to understand **"multiple outlet"**, for anyone who is not aware of this!

https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/angular-router-series-secondary-outlets-primer-139206595e2

Thank You

Comment: there is no limit on the outlets, however every outlet corresponds to a piece of code, that will be rendered there, and it affects the url. With more code your app will be loaded longer and there are some restrictions on url length. apart from these 2 I don't think there is any limit

Comment: Lets say iam using two more outlets, how the URL would be displayed? Something like ‘localhost:4200/home(router2:comp2)(router3:comp3)?

Comment: You cannot route this way like you have mentioned in your comment. For any parent or child components to be activated, you can make use of separate routes. Here's a kick starter: https://www.freakyjolly.com/angular-nested-routing-with-multiple-routeroutlet-using-loadchildren-having-own-router-modules-example-application/#.X_cQ8tgzbIU

Comment: We can, you can see here. 
https://medium.com/@natelapinski/hi-alejandro-thanks-for-the-feedback-im-glad-you-enjoyed-the-article-6e41978d9460.
Thanks for your answer and link

Comment: Thanks for letting me know @Yerrapotu. What I meant was you can specify more than 1 outlet in the route path specification a bit different as compared to normal routing. https://codeburst.io/primary-and-secondary-angular-router-outlets-5b065bcdb399

Comment: My apologies, I didn't frame question correctly in the first place. Now I got my answer.

Comment: @Andrei could you please post your answer as post. I will select that as correct one.

Comment: sure. just did it. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is no limit on the outlets, however every outlet corresponds to a piece of code, that will be rendered there, and it affects the url. With more code your app will be loaded longer and there are some restrictions on url length. apart from these 2 I don't think there is any limit

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use multiple `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` you can use it. There is no limit in angular but there are some best practices of using multiple 
place one  in app.component.html and if you have a number of featured modules then you can use separate  for each featured module.

======  app.component.html=====

```
<app-header></app-header>
<!-- router-outlet will emit an activate event any time a new component is being instantiated, and a deactivate event when it is being destroyed. -->
<!-- It will act as a placeholder that angular automatically fills the current route state-->
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

======= app-routing.ts =====

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' , canActivate : [AuthGuardService]},
  { path: 'dashboard',  component: DashboardComponent, canActivate : [AuthGuardService], data: {role: 'system'}},
  { path: 'featureModule', loadChildren: './module/featureModule.module#FeatureModule', canActivate : [AuthGuardService]},
  { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent }
];
```

and in `FeatureModule` add saparate `<router-outlet>` so all components in featuredModule will get rendered in FeatureModuleComponent.html.

featureModuleComponent.Html

```
<app-menu [sysType]="featureModule"></app-menu>
<div class="bg-mage" [ngStyle]="{'background-image': backgroundImage, 'height': customImgHeight} ">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet> <!-- router outlet of featured module -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> is there any limit?

No, there is no specific limit.